# Range of a function - trigonometric

Tags: trigonometry

Question:
Find the range of the function:
$$\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x$$

I really have no idea how to initiate this question. Please help me find a solution!

Answer (score 6):

$$f(x)=\sin^4x+\cos^4x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x$$

Using $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x,$

$$f(x)=1-\frac{\sin^22x}2$$

Using $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y,$

$$f(x)=1-\frac{1-\cos4x}4=\frac{3+\cos4x}4$$

Now for real $A,-1\le\cos A\le1$

Comment: And then we can just substitute the minimum and maximum value! Well that's an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^4 x+\cos ^4 x \leq \sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$ equality hold when $\sin^4 x = \sin^2 x$ and $\cos^4 x = \cos^2 x$

So $\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x \leq 1$ when $x=n\pi\;,n\in \mathbb{Z}$

and using Power mean Inequality

$\displaystyle \frac{(\sin^2 x)^2+(\cos^2 x)^2}{2}\geq \bigg(\frac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x}{2}\bigg)^2 = \frac{1}{4}$ and equality hold when $\sin^2 x = \cos^2 x$

So $\displaystyle \sin^4 x+\cos^4 x \geq \frac{1}{2}$ when $\displaystyle x=n\pi\pm \frac{\pi}{4}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

$$z=\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-2\sin^2x(1-\sin^2x)$$

Let $t=\sin x$

$$z=1-2t^2(1-t^2)=1-2t^2+2t^4=2(t^2-1/2)^2+1-1/2\\t=2(t^2-1/2)^2+1/2$$
Now we know that $t$ ranges from $-1$ to $1$, so that $t^2$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, put values.

Comment: Lost you on the last expansion :/

Comment: @Gummybears corrected

Comment: Okay lol I thought I just couldn't understand.